# Drawing ArUco's pose axes to wrong place

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, aruco

I am working on image processing project that detects ArUco markers and doing somethings according to those. When there is only one marker in the video or image everything works fine, but when I put another marker, the second ArUco marker's pose (axes) printing to the wrong place, not to the center of the marker. Please see the screenshot I shared for better understand.

The marker with the id[2] is fine. Pose axes are drawn to the center of marker.
But, the marker's pose axes with the id[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j5zYl.jpg) are drawn to some random point.

[co](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j5zYl.jpg)

Here is the code part of that detects ArUco markers and draws the axis.

```
while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    # Operations on the frame come here
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)  # Change grayscale
    aruco_dict = aruco.Dictionary_get(aruco.DICT_4X4_250)  # Specify marker size as 4x4, 5x5, 6x6
    parameters = aruco.DetectorParameters_create()  # Marker detection parameters
    # Lists of ids and the corners beloning to each marker
    corners, ids, rejected_img_points = aruco.detectMarkers(gray, aruco_dict,
                                                            parameters=parameters,
                                                            cameraMatrix=matrix_coefficients,
                                                            distCoeff=distortion_coefficients)

    try:    
        if np.all(ids is not None):  # If there are markers found by detector
            for i in range(0, len(ids)):  # Iterate in markers
                # Estimate pose of each marker and return the values rvec and tvec---different from camera coefficients
                rvec, tvec, markerPoints = aruco.estimatePoseSingleMarkers(corners[i], 0.02, matrix_coefficients,
                                                                           distortion_coefficients)
                (rvec - tvec).any()  # get rid of that nasty numpy value array error
                aruco.drawDetectedMarkers(frame, corners)  # Draw A square around the markers
                aruco.drawAxis(frame, matrix_coefficients, distortion_coefficients, rvec, tvec, 0.01)  # Draw axis

                c_x = (corners[i][0][0][0] + corners[i][0][1][0] + corners[i][0][2][0] + corners[i][0][3][0]) / 4 # X coordinate of marker's center
                c_y = (corners[i][0][0][1] + corners[i][0][1][1] + corners[i][0][2][1] + corners[i][0][3][1]) / 4 # Y coordinate of marker's center
                cv2.putText(frame, "id"+str(ids[i]), (int(c_x), int(c_y)), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (50,225,250), 2)

    except:
        if ids is None or len(ids) == 0:
            print("******************************************************")
            print("*************** Marker Detection Failed **************")
            print("******************************************************")
```

Comment: Indentation of `while True` looks erronous. Maybe you should edit the code block properly.

Comment: @vahdet Fixed now. That was because of copy-paste, the whole code is approximately 500 lines.